# ASP.NET A/B Split Testing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, testing

Does anyone know of any good resources (books, articles, existing software, etc...) for learning how to implement `A/B` `split` testing in `ASP.NET`?

Comment: Please accept helpful answers, that encourages the members of the community to respond to your questions, thanks

Comment: Google Optimizer is not available yet. You can use Google content experiments in Google analytics now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FairlyCertain is an AB Testing library for ASP.NET](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlycertain/) that's worth checking out.  It drops seamlessly into your project and doesn't require any of the javascript voodoo that Google Website Optimizer uses (which kills your site's performance and SEO all in one shot).

I've been using it for a few of my projects for several months now with good success.

Comment: Thank you. At a glance, this appears to be exactly what I was looking for. I'll definitely be checking it out once I start focusing on optimizing my website.

Answer (score 5):

I have just written a short article describing a technique for doing split testing in ASP.Net MVC.  You can check it out [here](http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/05/11/Split-Testing-(AB-Testing)-in-ASPNet-Mvc.aspx)

It will not take much work to make it work with traditional asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into this post again, you may find this useful:
http://github.com/htayebi/AbTestMaster

It's an open source a/b testing framework for ASP.NET MVC which allows you to write the results either in sql database or csv file. You can download the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AbTestMaster/) or if interested, go through the code in github.

Answer (score 1):

Google website optimizer?

http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer/b/index.html

http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=14309

http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71976

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Display Modes to achieve A/B testing.

But Display Modes just support simple problems by default.

If you already implement Display Modes in some other scenario. You can consider DisplayModeMatrix (just google it). It helps you use Display Modes more efficiency.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DisplayModeMatrix/

Wth Display Modes you can simply delete/rename views after A/B testing to clean up your project.